# Change password validator to look for a specific password

Tags: javascript, html

I need my code to use a specific password that I set but right now it just does it by the number of characters. I can't figure out how to change my code to work with a specific password.

This is my code. I don't want to change the HTML much because that will mess with my CSS.

```js
function myfunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("pass");

  if (x.type === "password") {
    x.type = "text";
  } else {
    x.type = "password";
  }
}

function validate() {
  var password = document.getElementById("pass");
  var length = document.getElementById("length");

  if (password.value.length >= 8) {
    alert("Login Succesfull");
    window.location.replace("gamepage.html");
    return false;
  } else {
    alert("Login Failed")
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="form">
  <h1>Login Here</h1>
  <p>Password :</p>
  <input type="password" name="" placeholder="Password Here" id="pass">
  <input type="checkbox" onclick="myfunction()">
  <input type="submit" name="" value="Login" onclick="validate()">
</div>

<div>
  <p id="length"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: change `password.value.length >= 8`?

Comment: what would I change it to

Comment: `password.value.length >= 8` would become something like `password.value == 'yourPassword'` of course this isn't secure at all but fine for learning basics